# Remove git from terminal (online solutions not working)(Mac OSX)

Tags: macos, git, github

I used my old github account and now that is deactivated and i have a new one now. I want it to communicate with my new github username. I've tried many internet solutions and re-installing git and the command line tools. Whenever i type in `git remote -v`

`origin https://github.com/OldUsername/App.git (fetch)
 origin https://github.com/OldUsername/App.git (push)`

This account is now deactivated so there is no way to use it, I've tried doing the

```
git config --global user.email "YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS"
git config user.name "Username"
```

I've been trying for hours and still can't figure out how to get my command line to be able to push to new projects under my new username.

Comment: Try it without `--global`. You might have project-specific settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the push setting for the remote in your repository config.

Either go hand edit /.git/config or try something like

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/NewUsername/app.git
```

Answer (score 0):

Remotes are part of a local repository. You can add, remove, rename, or reconfigure them with various `git-remote` subcommands. You might consider just nuking the current repository directory if it doesn't contain anything you value and cloning or creating a new one.

Alternatively, you can set the URL for a remote using:

```
git remote set-url origin <new URL>
```